# What is the biblical argument for forgiveness ruling out punishment for grievous crimes?

Tags: biblical-basis, forgiveness, punishment

It seems to me that most Christians today think that forgiveness of **grievous** crimes implies lack of punishment of the criminal. To my knowledge (by far complete, to be sure) of the New Testament, **nowhere** is this outrageous idea to be found. So, my question is: Is there any part of the Bible where it is said or from where it might be implied that this would be God's wish for how us mortals should treat criminals? To be clear, I want to emphasize, I'm not talking about petty "crimes" like bad-mouthing, insults, even cheating. The Bible is clear about these. I'm talking about (mass) murder, (mass) rape, pedophilia. Forgiveness, definitely. But also punishment suitable for the crime, why not?

Comment: What is the basis for your statement  "It seems to me that most Christians today think that forgiveness of grievous crimes implies lack of punishment of the criminal".  Most of the Christians I have met would not say that.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Comment: Is your question in relation to “Christ’s finished work” where some “believers” insist that no “Sins” they might commit after justification warrant Punishment or  temporal penalty, and how their forgiveness seems to lack the forgiveness Christ offers the believers who accept that teaching?

Comment: @Adam I am happy to hear that and hope that my surmise is false for most Christians. However, here in Europe, it seems to me that it is this way.